# Start-job calling another star-job for-each loop

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am newbie to Powershell.

This is just a sample code to explain my issue.

The following code partially works.  Not sure if the issue is Start-job calling other start-job command or calling Scriptblock to another scriptblock an issue.  Could you please suggest whats wrong?

I receive output in 1.txt but not 2.txt

```
$writes3=
{
 param($a)  
$gettingtime ={
param($i)
$a=get-date
$b="$a and iteration is $i"
Out-File -Filepath D:\2.txt -InputObject $b -Append
}

$z=get-date
$c="$z and iteration is $a"
Out-File -Filepath D:\1.txt -InputObject $c -Append
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $gettingtime -ArgumentList $a
}

$f=10
for ($a=1; $a -le $f; $a++)
{
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $writes3 -ArgumentList $a
}
```

Comment: `$gettingtime` is not defined in `$writes3` script block.

Comment: $writes3=

{
param($a)

$gettingtime ={

param($i)

$a=get-date
$b="$a and iteration is $i"
Out-File -Filepath D:\2.txt -InputObject $b -Append

}


$z=get-date
$c="$z and iteration is $a"
Out-File -Filepath D:\1.txt -InputObject $c -Append
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $gettingtime -ArgumentList $a
}



$f=10
for ($a=1; $a -le $f; $a++)
{
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $writes3 -ArgumentList $a
}
Thanks for your response! But still it didnt execute fully

Comment: @GRS You can edit your original question instead of putting it all in a comment. That'll make it much easier to read.

Comment: Thanks avojak. Editign the original question. Put in $getting_time within $writeS3 and still didnt work

Comment: Add `Get-Job | Wait-Job | Out-Null` as last command in `$writes3`.

Comment: Which PSversion are you using ?